# Linux Debian Google cloud VM instance

Tags: linux, fuse

I have been trying to mount a google storage bucket on one of my instances. I followed the directions [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/gcs-buckets). This is the error I get.

> E: Unable to locate package gcsfuse E: Unable to locate package

What am I doing wrong ? It's a debian set up 32 GB 4 CPUs.

Comment: Looks like either `gcsfuse` was not properly installed. When / at which step of the `gcsfuse` install did this error occur exactly? When running `sudo apt-get install gcsfuse` I am assuming?

Comment: Yes, that was when it occurred.

Answer (score 1):

`gcsfuse` is a tool that needs to be installed on the actual VM. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/installing.md) (for Debian jessie):

> 1 - Add the gcsfuse distribution URL as a package source and import
>   its public key:
>
> ```
> export GCSFUSE_REPO=gcsfuse-`lsb_release -c -s`
> echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt $GCSFUSE_REPO main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gcsfuse.list
> curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
> ```
>
> 2 - Update the list of packages available and install gcsfuse.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install gcsfuse
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install fuse -y
curl -L -O https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/releases/download/v0.39.2/gcsfuse_0.39.2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg --install gcsfuse_0.39.2_amd64.deb
rm gcsfuse_0.39.2_amd64.deb
```